# CMSParagraphComponent does not render HTML tag attributes after 2105 Upgrade

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

After upgrading to SAP Commerce 2105 Patch 13 from 1811, components with type CMSParagraphComponent do not have **img**, **span** HTML tags and  HTML tag attributes like **class**, **style**.

Before upgrade HTML was displaying in the page as following:

```html
<div class="content">
    <div class="size-guide__area active" data-js="size-guide-area">
        <div>
            <div class="size-guide__close" data-js="size-guide-close">
                My text
                <span class="icon-close-circle"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My component is covered with `<true class="yCmsComponent"></true>` after upgrade somehow.

After upgrade HTML is displaying as following:

```html
<true class="yCmsComponent">
    <div class="content">
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    My Text
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</true>
```

impex:

```
INSERT_UPDATE CMSParagraphComponent;$contentCV[unique=true];uid[unique=true];name;&componentRef;content[lang=$lang];
;;chartParagraph;Chart Paragraph;chartParagraph;"<div class='size-guide__area' data-js='size-guide-area'>
                                <div>
                                    <div class='size-guide__close' data-js='size-guide-close'>
                                        My text
                                        <span class='icon-close-circle'></span>
                                    </div>
```

usage in tag file:

```
<cms:component uid="chartParagraph" evaluateRestriction="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CMSParagraphComponentRenderer` class is sanitizing HTML. Rules are defined in `HtmlSanitizerPolicyProvider` class. It is checking a property before sanitizing. I solved issue by changing the property in storefront extension. You may customize `HtmlSanitizerPolicyProvider` class to have a safer solution. Changing following property may cause an issue, it is not the safest solution.

In the `project.properties` file of the storefront extension, add following property.

```
cms.components.allowUnsafeJavaScript=true
```